# Mi App se detiene antes de solicitar permisos

Tags: android

He estado realizando una aplicación en Android Studio el cual solo obtengo la imei del dispositivo al presionar un botón.

El problema que tengo es que al iniciar la aplicación esta se detiene y luego solicita permiso. luego de solicitar los permisos funciona como yo quiero

adjunto código

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TelephonyManager manager;
    TextView txtMensaje;
    private View btn;
    private final int REQUEST_ACCESS_PHONE = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtMensaje = findViewById(R.id.txtIMEI);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btnSolicitar);
        manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        final String IMEI;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_ACCESS_PHONE);
        }


        IMEI = manager.getDeviceId();


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtMensaje.setText(IMEI);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_PHONE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permiso concedido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permiso Denegado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

este es el error que arroja el catlog

```
10-15 14:19:16.400 742-15047/? E/WifiMonitor: handleEvent unknown: 14  CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

10-15 14:19:17.667 742-855/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateSavedNetworkHistory(): try "milita"WPA_PSK SSID="milita" milita [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS] ajst=0

10-15 14:19:17.668 742-855/? E/WifiConfigStore:         got known scan result c0:05:c2:7e:85:69 key : "milita"WPA_PSK num: 1 rssi=-47 freq=2437

10-15 14:19:17.671 742-855/? E/WifiConfigStore:  writeKnownNetworkHistory() num networks:3 needWrite=false

10-15 14:19:17.671 742-855/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false

10-15 14:19:17.967 742-742/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 341 num clients 14

10-15 14:19:17.968 742-742/? E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=12877 Rx=13528
```

Comment: Bienvenido Felipe, si deseas desarrollar en Android es super importante el uso del LogCat, ¿Que error se muestra en el LogCat?. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me pasaba algo similar cuando usaba TelephoneManager, asi que busque información y una solución la cual me funciono fue obtener el IMEI de esta manera:

```
String myIMEI = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Agregue los permisos al manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Y pedi los permisos en Android 6.0:

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
    this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE );

if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso :( .");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE }, 225);
} else {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso wiii!");
}
```